# Форма регистрации юзеров с указанием группы в Symfony2

Tags: symfony, forms, php

Стоит задача предоставить возможность юзерам при регистрации выбрать свою группу. Работа с юзерами на базе `FOSUserBundle`, расширил форму:

```
// Acme\UserBundle\Form\Type\RegistrationFormType.php

$builder->add('my_group', 'choice', array(
    'choices' => array(
        'group_a' => 'А',
        'group_b' => 'Б',
    ),            
    'data' => 'group_b',
    'expanded'  => true,
));
```

Теперь надо сделать валидацию, чтобы через `my_group` могло проходить либо `group_a`, либо `group_b`.

И вторая задача: после успешной валидации, надо создать юзера, а на базе поля `my_group`, добавить его в группу, например, таким образом:

```
$user->addGroup($this->get('fos_user.group_manager')->findGroupByName('group_a'));

$this->get('fos_user.user_manager')->updateUser($this->getUser());
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как это сделать, куда копать?

Answer (score 1):

Как же формы и валидаторы в Symfony2 отличаются от Symfony1.4...

Судя по беглому пролистыванию вот такой доки - [Validation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/validation.html), надо в конфиг валидации добавлять твою форму и в ней описывать правила валидации.

А добавление в группу наверное сделать в postExecute, хотя не знаю, насколько это архитектурно верно.

Comment: доки все уже перечитал :) но из-за нехватки опыта, немогу разобраться как имнно данную задачу решить :(

про добавление, тоже надо более конкретную рекомендацию, куда всёже копать...

Comment: Схему валидации надо добавлять в src/ТВОЙ_ПРОЕКТ/ТВОЙ_БАНДЛ/Resources/config/validation.yml

postExecute в контроллере: 
public function postExecute() {
 $this->get('fos_user.user_manager')->updateUser($this->getUser());
}
Т.е. когда контроллер отрабатывает и вызывается в конце postExecute - он имеет доступ ко всем данным, которыми оперировал контроллер. Значит, есть доступ к пользователю и группе.

Comment: Во, на Хабре опубликовали по формам и их устройству:

http://habrahabr.ru/post/149444/

http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html

Comment: https://symfony.com.ua/doc/current/forms.html - перевод на русский http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html

Comment: и по валидации - https://symfony.com.ua/doc/current/validation.html